# SQL Server find a particular string that follows a particular string

Tags: sql-server

Let me try to make this as easy to understand as possible. 
I have a table with a column that is called 'Script_Text'. This column contains a script. Like, a really long script with class name, function name, the whole drill.
I am trying to find the function names on all these scripts. I don't want to go through every one of them individually.

This is NOT what I am looking for:

> ```
> select * from table
> where script_text like '%function%'
> ```

Script or query, doesn't matter. Want it for SQL Server. My database has not more than 200 tables. Don't care about efficiency. 
Thanks

EDIT 1: My assumption on what the query would look like might throw you off, just ignore it. I might be plain stupid on how I think this would work.
Also, all functions start with `Function` keyword. For instance: `Function GetUserName()`. I want my query to return `GetUserName()`.

EDIT 2: I know this is confusing to follow. It is confusing to articulate it in words in MY head. Let me give more examples.

One of the tables I am working with is `ObjectSymbol`. This table has 3 columns. `SymbolName`, `Description`, `Script_Text`. 
Contents of the Script_Text column for one particular symbolname is this

```
Function PostSearch() As Long
    ' Delete any @DFLT or @T records from the search results
    DO something
    ' Do more things
End Function
```

A successful query would return PostSearch() for that particular symbolname.

EDIT 3:

```
imports System    
imports System.Diagnostics    
Imports System.XML    
Imports System.Data    
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Class HookScript    
 Inherits FcProcFuncSetEvent

Function presave() as long
    Do stuff here
End Function

Function IngrPostRowUpdate() as Long
Do more stuff here
   RETURN 1
End Function

Function postsave() As Long
    Do some more stuff here
End Function

Private Function GetValue(val as Object) as String
    If IsDBNull(val) Then
        GetValue = ""
    Else
        GetValue = CStr(val)
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

`GetValue` is what is being returned by the query.

Comment: Could you try to give more examples/data?  I can't see much difference between what you don't want and what you do want - all you have really asked there is that you don't get a select *

Comment: is there any specific character after 'function' word? always one space?

Comment: @Cato Sorry about that. I have edited the question so it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @McNets One space. That is standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

First I declare a table variable to *mock-up* a test scenario.

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeScript NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
 (
 N'Do something here
 blah
 blah
 private function HereIsAFunctionName(){
     Some body
 }
 public function SomeOtherFunction(){blah}
 private function OneMore(){
     Body
 }
 ')
 ,(
 N'Do something here
 blah
 blah
 private function ThisIsAFunction(){
     Some body
 }
 ');
```

The first part (a CTE) will use a string-split-trick to create XML chunks by replacing the word `function` (with blanks) by `</x><x>`. Then you can read the beginning of each chunk up to the opening `(`. You might read to the closing `)` to get the paramter's list.

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT SomeScript AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N' function ',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) AS SplitMe
    FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT Casted.ID
      ,LEFT(x.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),CHARINDEX('(',x.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'))-1) AS Part 
FROM Casted
OUTER APPLY Casted.SplitMe.nodes(N'x[position()!=1]') AS A(x)
```

The result

```
ID  Part
1   HereIsAFunctionName
1   SomeOtherFunction
1   OneMore
2   ThisIsAFunction
```

### EDIT Same for VB-syntax

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(SomeScript,'end function','') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N' function ',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) AS SplitMe
    FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT Casted.ID
      ,LEFT(x.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),CHARINDEX(')',x.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'))) AS Part 
FROM Casted
OUTER APPLY Casted.SplitMe.nodes(N'x[position()!=1]') AS A(x)
```

### UPDATE

Your problem was caused by line breaks, where I expected blanks...

Try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeScript NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
 (
 N'Do something here
 blah
 blah
 private function HereIsAFunctionName(){
     Some body
 }
 public function SomeOtherFunction(){blah}
 private function OneMore(){
     Body
 }
 ')
 ,(
 N'imports System    
imports System.Diagnostics    
Imports System.XML    
Imports System.Data    
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Class HookScript    
 Inherits FcProcFuncSetEvent

Function presave() as long
    Do stuff here
End Function

Function IngrPostRowUpdate() as Long
Do more stuff here
   RETURN 1
End Function

Function postsave() As Long
    Do some more stuff here
End Function

Private Function GetValue(val as Object) as String
    If IsDBNull(val) Then
        GetValue = ""
    Else
        GetValue = CStr(val)
    End If
End Function
End Class
 ');
```

--The query

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SomeScript,'end function',''),CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(10),' ') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N' function ',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) AS SplitMe
    FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT Casted.ID
      ,LEFT(x.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),CHARINDEX(')',x.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'))) AS Part 
FROM Casted
OUTER APPLY Casted.SplitMe.nodes(N'x[position()!=1]') AS A(x);
```

Comment: In the original poster's example, the script has "Function foo().... End Function", which means you have to deal with the case where you have occurrences of the 'Function' keyword NOT followed by a function name.  But that final "End Function" could conceivably have a space following it, you never know. A slightly complicating factor, but you should use that script in the original question in your test data here.

Comment: @pmbAustin OK, VB-syntax... Just replace ALL `End Function` with something else before you do this trick...

Comment: @pmbAustin True, the end function will definitely cause confusion. Did not even think about that.

Comment: @Shnugo This looks promising. Let me try this out.

Comment: @Shnugo This KINDA works. Here is what happened.
The declare part created a table. It has the right entries in it. When I cast and select from CTE, it returns all the entries that is in the temp table. BUT.... The script column is NULL for all the rows EXCEPT 1. There are 4 other functions in that script but it returns only this 1 function out of the 14 rows. 
Any idea why? I can provide with the script if needed.

Comment: @sKrishna Please provide a (reduced) real-life script... You would not need the *declare part*. Use your actual table in the place of `@YourTable`.

Comment: @Shnugo Edited the original post with the script. That is literally the script in the table, except it has codes instead of `do something here`.

Comment: @Shnugo I've never gotten people being overly dramatic about someone answering their question right, but I get it now. THANK YOU!

Comment: @sKrishna I'm glad to help you!

Comment: @Shnugo If I was to use LTRIM and/or RTRIM on the function name, where would I do it? I just noticed that the indentation of the script some times get in the way of returning all function names.

Comment: @sKrishna please provide a sample... You might replace all tabs (`char(9)`) with blanks